# Issue with implementing unique_purchases column in main table using leftJoin in Grid ResourceModel

Tags: database, uicomponent, sql, resource-model

I have a SQL query that does what I need

```
SELECT ipi.*, COALESCE(unique_purchases, 0) AS unique_purchases FROM mst_inventory_planner_inventory AS ipi LEFT JOIN ( SELECT product_id, COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS unique_purchases FROM sales_order_item GROUP BY product_id ) AS soi ON ipi.product_id = soi.product_id;
```

I have trouble implementing an equivalent in Grid ResourceModel.

I tried using another join as a reference, but it didn't work

customers_subscribed join

```
)->joinLeft(
                ['pas' => $this->getTable('product_alert_stock')],
                'main_table.product_id=pas.product_id',
                [
                    'customers_subscribed' => new \Zend_Db_Expr("COUNT(pas.customer_id)"),
                ]
```

my attempt to do the same for unique_purchases

```
    )->joinLeft(
        ['soi' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item')],
        'main_table.product_id = soi.product_id',
        ['unique_purchases' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(DISTINCT soi.order_id)')]
```

The site and grid stopped working after this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you check the magento log file after implementing this code?

Comment: it doesn't write anything to it. i assume it because it can't process the query.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using subquery

```
$uniquePurchasesSubquery = $this->getConnection()->select()
            ->from(
                ['sales_order_item'],
                [
                    'product_id',
                    'unique_purchases' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(DISTINCT order_id)')
                ]
            )
            ->group('product_id');
```

joinLeft

```
)->joinLeft(
                ['purchases' => new \Zend_Db_Expr("($uniquePurchasesSubquery) ")],
                'main_table.product_id = purchases.product_id',
                ['unique_purchases' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('COALESCE(purchases.unique_purchases, 0)')]
```

It could be done better. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is also an issue with a UI listing.
if you connect this class it becomes barely possible to load it.

How do I optimize it? Since the query is too heavy, there should be some kind of preventive mechanism that will populate this custom column under a certain condition, for example, when a certain date range is picked in the UI date range picker. Is it possible?
Please suggest some solutions.

```
<?php
   
class UniquePurchases extends Column
{
    protected $orderItemCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderItemCollectionFactory $orderItemCollectionFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->orderItemCollectionFactory = $orderItemCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                if (isset($item['product_id'])) {
                    try {
                        // Load order item collection
                        $orderItemCollection = $this->orderItemCollectionFactory->create();
                        $orderItemCollection->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $item['product_id']);

                        // Filter by date range
                        $fromDate = '2021-01-01'; // Example start date
                        $toDate = '2021-04-01';   // Example end date
                        $orderItemCollection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate]);

                        $orderItemCollection->getSelect()->group('order_id');

                        // Get the count of unique purchases
                        $uniquePurchasesCount = $orderItemCollection->getSize();

                        // Set the value in the column
                        $item[$fieldName] = $uniquePurchasesCount;
                    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                        // Handle NoSuchEntityException for non-existing product_id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }


}
```